# Effect of killing Gimp to increase faster closing of program

Tags: gimp, kill

Despite my saving changes to images, Gimp insists on opening a dialog every time I want to leave.

What would be the effect of killing Gimp to exit pronto?

Thanks.

Comment: What does the dialog say?

Comment: There is one image with unsaved changes. @waltinator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The risks

If you kill Gimp, it won't save options for the next run, which may or may not be important. You also run the risk to kill it before it is finished exporting to disk your last image (exporting a big PNG takes time).

#### A better way

Gimp considers that an image is saved only if it has been saved as XCF. All other formats will potentially make you lose something: layers, channels, selection, paths...

If you read carefully the exit dialog, it tells you you can use <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> to exit and discard all changes. So you can take the habit of blindly typing <kbd>Ctrl-Q</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> to exit (but someday you'll regret it).

Comment: Thanks. I try not to blindly do anything. Ctrl Q is all it took to shut that puppy down.

Comment: @fixit If the answer worked for you consider marking it as accepted.